# How can I suppress the "Instance of linked .rvt file needs Coordination Review" dialog?

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I need to suppress the *Instance of linked .rvt file needs Coordination Review* dialog while I'm running an add-in that opens multiple models because I don't want the user to need to click through a bunch of dialogs.  I've added an event handler to `UIApplication.DialogBoxShowing` and it checks if the dialog has `HelpId == 1011` (found [here](http://spiderinnet.typepad.com/blog/2011/07/taskdialog-vs-dialogbox-id-vs-helpid-and-dialogboxshowing-event.html)) which is the dialog that I'm looking for.  However, when I try the `e.OverrideResult` method it always seems to cancel the action.  I've tried `TaskDialogResult.Ok` and `DialogResult.Ok` but both of them cancel the action.

Here is my event handler:

```
private void application_DialogBoxShowing(object sender, 
  DialogBoxShowingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.HelpId == 1011)
    e.OverrideResult((int)TaskDialogResult.Ok);
}
```

What dialog result can I pass to make the action continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an event handler for when dialog boxes show I decided to make an event handler that ties into the `UIApplication.Application.FailuresProcessing` event.  I found the information on the failure API from the [Building Coder](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/11/failure-api-take-two.html).

The code below will suppress *all* warnings.

```
private void Application_FailuresProcessing(object sender, 
  FailuresProcessingEventArgs e)
{
  FailuresAccessor failuresAccessor = e.GetFailuresAccessor();
  IEnumerable<FailureMessageAccessor> failureMessages =
    failuresAccessor.GetFailureMessages();

  foreach (FailureMessageAccessor failureMessage in failureMessages)
  {
    if (failureMessage.GetSeverity() == FailureSeverity.Warning)
      failuresAccessor.DeleteWarning(failureMessage)
  }

  e.SetProcessingResult(FailureProcessingResult.Continue)
}
```

You can add an if statement checking for `failureMessage.GetFailureDefinitionId().Guid == new Guid("3d983f31-9ee3-4c3a-bed8-663b32cecec5")` if you only want to suppress the specific coordination review message.